# how to handle null values on firebase transaction api

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

I have a function that is decrementing user credits on firebase realtime database values with a transaction.
As suggested in [Firebase transaction API call current data is null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39194310/8056504) transaction current value occasionally returns as null.

I've made a guard for the null case and returned 0 so the transaction function fires again until it gets the actual credit value.

```
function charge(cost, description) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const creditRef = db.ref(`credits/${userid}`)
    ref.transaction(function(current) {
      console.log(`${description} current value: ${current}`)
      if (current === null) {
        console.log(`${description} returns 0 `)
        return 0
      }
      if (cost > current || current === 0) {
        //not enough credits return without committing
        console.log(`${description} aborts `)
        return
      }
      //commit the new credit value
      console.log(`${description} returns ${current} - ${cost}`)
      return current - cost
    },
    (error, commited, snapshot) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error)
      }
      else {
        if (commited) {
            //user has enough credits
            resolve()
        }
        else {
            //not enough credits
            reject('no commit')
        }
    }
  })
}
```

However, in a case where 2 charge functions are fired back to back, the second call will get a current value of 0 (which is probably the returned 0 on the first charge call). So it will prematurely exit assuming that the user doesn't have enough credits. When both functions resolve the final credit value will be 3 and the second charge call will be ignored.

```
// User has 5 credits 
charge(3, 'first call').then(() => console.log('first call success')
// transaction function returns 0 since current value is null
charge(2, 'second call').then(() => console.log('second call success')
```

Console log output:

> first call current value: null
>
> first call returns 0
>
> second call current value: 0
>
> second call aborts
>
> first call current value: 5
>
> first call returns 5 - 3
>
> first call success
>
> second call no commit

So the second charge call ends up not going through when user had enough credits.
What is the proper way to handle firebase transaction null value cases?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what the problem is. If the user has no credits (either because their `credits` value is `0`, or because they don't have a value for `credits`), their transaction will be rejected. If the rejection turns out to be wrong (because the value in the database has changed), the function will be retried.

Comment: If you suspect the `return 0` is causing your problem, I'd suggest replacing it with a `return` without a value and see if you can still reproduce the problem.

Comment: But if I do `return` instead `return 0` function will complete without committing, when I want it to be retried with the actual current value. (which is not null in this case)

Comment: Returning without a value aborts the transaction. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#transaction

Comment: If I do `return` neither of the `charge()` calls actually decrement the credit value.

Comment: As I said, I think I'm not understanding the problem. Can you set up a reproduction that I can look at somewhere? If that is not feasible, can you change your code to: 1) `console.log(current)` at the start, 2) `console.log` the return value (or lack thereof) at all three `return` statements, 3) edit your question to include what you get (including an indication about which client/run logged which lines)?

Comment: I've edited the question with more clarification.

Comment: Thanks! That was really helpful, and allowed me to answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case you get `null` from the database, you should make no change. Since you get `null`, also return `null`.

So:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref(`59571450`)
function charge(cost, description) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ref.transaction(function(current) {
      console.log(`${description} current value: ${current}`);
      if (current === null) {
        console.log(`${description} returns null`)
        return null;
      }
      if (cost > current) {
        //not enough credits return without committing
        console.log(`${description} aborts `)
        return
      }
      //commit the new credit value
      console.log(`${description} returns ${current} - ${cost}`)
      return current - cost
    },
    (error, commited, snapshot) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error)
      }
      else {
        if (commited) {
            //user has enough credits
            resolve()
        }
        else {
            //not enough credits
            reject('no commit')
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
                     

ref.set(5).then(() => {
  charge(3, 'first call').then(() => console.log('first call success'))
  charge(2, 'second call').then(() => console.log('second call success'))
})
```

When run this gives this output:

> first call current value: null
>
> first call returns null
>
> second call current value: null
>
> second call returns null
>
> first call current value: 5
>
> first call returns 5 - 3
>
> second call current value: 2
>
> second call returns 2 - 2
>
> first call success
>
> second call success

For a working version of this code, see: https://jsbin.com/xefebul/1/edit?js,console