# Firebase Transaction MutableData showing Nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have a path that I run a Transaction on. I check to see if the value is nil before proceeding. If it is nil I abort and if not I continue. The issue is the value isn't nil but the mutable data is saying it is.

db:

```
@posts
   @postId_abc
      -date: ....
      -views: 0
```

Transaction:

```
let viewsPath = Database.database().reference()
                   .child("posts")
                   .child("postId_abc")
                   .child("views")

viewsPath.runTransactionBlock({ (mutableData: MutableData) -> TransactionResult in

    let doesViewsExist = mutableData.value as? Int // I also tried Double
    if doesViewsExist == nil {
                        
        return TransactionResult.abort() // "views" value is 0
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expect behavior. When you start a transaction the SDK immediately calls your transaction handler with its best guess of the current value of the node. Most often that guess will be `nil`, as the client has no better knowledge yet.

So you will have to **not** abort the transaction, but instead set another value on the mutable data, for example `0`. It doesn't really matter much what that value is, as the transaction will be retried anyway.

For more background on this, see:

- [Firebase realtime database transaction handler gets called twice most of the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57130534/firebase-realtime-database-transaction-handler-gets-called-twice-most-of-the-tim/57134276#57134276), with an ASCII chart of the flow
- [Firebase runTransaction not working - MutableData is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818946/firebase-runtransaction-not-working-mutabledata-is-null)
- [how to handle null values on firebase transaction api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59571450/how-to-handle-null-values-on-firebase-transaction-api)