# Why is a transaction in my Firebase Cloud function not able to retrieve data which exists and thus, failing?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, transactions

In my 2nd generation cloud function i have the following code:

```
export const roomEnter = functions.https.onCall(async (request: any) => {

  // initial validation to verify user authentication and valid request data passes first
  ...

  const roomRef = admin.database().ref(`rooms/${request.data.roomId}`);
  const roomSnapshot = await roomRef.once("value");
  const testDataExists = {
    exists: roomSnapshot.exists(),
    data: roomSnapshot.val()
  };
  functions.logger.log("[room enter] CHECK ROOM EXISTS:", JSON.stringify(testDataExists));

  // In the logs, the data that exists DOES print to the console successfully

  const transactionRef = admin.database().ref(`rooms/${request.data.roomId}`);
  const transactionResult = await transactionRef.transaction((currentData) => {
    functions.logger.log("[room enter] Transaction current data:", JSON.stringify(currentData));

    // In the logs, `currentData` prints as `null`, why?
    // As a result, the transaction never gets beyond this condition and fails i assume after it has exhausted all internal retries

    if (currentData !== null) {
      if (currentData.memberTotal) {
        currentData.memberTotal += 1;
      } else {
        currentData.memberTotal = 1;
      }
      return currentData;
    } else {
      functions.logger.log("[room enter] Transaction needs to retry, room current data is null", {
        roomId: request.data.roomId
      });
      return; // Returning undefined should cause Firebase to retry the transaction
    }
  });

  if (transactionResult.committed) {
    // never able to reach this point
  } else {
    functions.logger.log("[room enter] transaction to increment member total failed");
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", "transaction to increment member total failed", {
      customData: {
        roomId: request.data.roomId
      }
    });
  }

  ...
});
```

The test `read` i do immediately prior to the transaction is only there as a test to confirm that the data exists.

And as noted in the code comments above, the transaction fails despite the reference path to existing data having been confirmed to exist.

Other than attempting to log errors everywhere possible, i am not sure how to troubleshoot this issue.

Other cloud functions i have which do not use transactions are able to read and write to the database without issue.

The only additional info i have aside from the logs, is that client side the error is reported to the client as a 500 internal server error along with the response which does include the error response containing the message `transaction to increment member total failed`.

With respect to my database security rules, as a test, despite the fact that this should have no relevance to my correctly authenticated admin SDK, i have set `".write": true` for `rooms` and `rooms/$roomId` in-order to exclude this as a possible cause.

So, why is `currentData` `null` inside the transaction?
What else can i do to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database transaction handlers will almost always be called with a `null` value in the mutable data initially, no matter what the actual value in the database is.

This is because the SDK immediately calls your handler with its best guess to the current value, and that'll usually be `null`. Your code will need to handler this situation, so that the SDK can then send the null-and-new-value to the server, realize that its guess was wrong, and try again.

This has been covered quite a few times over the years, and probably explained better in some of those cases than I did here, so I recommend checking out:

- [Firebase realtime database transaction handler gets called twice most of the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57130534/firebase-realtime-database-transaction-handler-gets-called-twice-most-of-the-tim) (including an ASCII art diagram of the flow)
- [Firebase runTransaction not working - MutableData is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818946/firebase-runtransaction-not-working-mutabledata-is-null)
- [how to handle null values on firebase transaction api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59571450/how-to-handle-null-values-on-firebase-transaction-api)
- [Firebase transaction reads null at path even when there is data at that path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65414653/firebase-transaction-reads-null-at-path-even-when-there-is-data-at-that-path/65415636#65415636)
- [Avoid obtaining null currentData at first reading in a Firebase transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66143562/avoid-obtaining-null-currentdata-at-first-reading-in-a-firebase-transaction/66143737#66143737)

Comment: SO's search functionality did not return any of these excellent references, so thank you for sharing, and thank you for the immediate response. I know we are supposed to refrain from saying a thank you, but the speed of the response warranted one as far as i am concerned. WITH THAT SAID, i cannot use a default value, and i cannot abort, so how would i handle this as I assume i cannot pass a value into the transaction to use as the starting value.

Comment: What modification can i make for the transaction to retry? Because, it seems that since i do not see subsequent errors write to the console, i have to assume it does not currently retry. In the meantime i am going to attempt to remove the else case with the `return;` statement as a solution.

Comment: You "just" need to get the SDK to retry, so any value you return is fine really.

Comment: I just tried removing the `} else { return; }` which, as per your last comment, would not work, and it did not. I am not clear on how to get the SDK to retry the transaction other than to implement a retry mechanism manually. Should I? Is there an SDK configuration setting i am not aware of for this? In the meantime i am going to try to return `false`.

Comment: `if (currentData == null) return "anything";`

Comment: `return false;` actually worked, looking at the logs, i see it print as `null` initially just as before, and subsequently, retries, and prints the data successfully. I assume `return false` is an acceptable return statement with respect to code legibility given that it works vs returning some arbitrary value.

Comment: An afterthought, since it seems you likely have some influence over at Firebase, i was not able to find any documentation on writing a transaction in a cloud function for the realtime database. This was the first place i looked for answers to no avail.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working.  --- There is nothing specific to it being in a Cloud Functions for this edge-case, it'd happen with any SDK on any platform.