# Nodejs Firebase Transaction - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that uses a transaction to updates the players in a game. When the /players is null, i am trying to return a Map, but i get "Maximum call stack size exceeded".

Here is my cloud function:

```
export const addUserToGame = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    // Expected inputs - game_id(from data) and UID(from context)

    if (context.auth == null) {
        return {
            "status": 403,
            "message": "You are not authorized to access this feature"
        };
    }

    const uid = context.auth.uid;
    const game_id = data.game_id;

    let gameIDRef = gamesRef.child(game_id);
    return gameIDRef.once("value", function (snapshot) {

        let players: Map<String, Number> = snapshot.child("players").val();
        let max_players: Number = snapshot.child("max_players").val();
        if (players != null && players.has(uid)) {
            return {
                "status": 403,
                "message": "Player already in the game"
            }
        } else if (players != null && players.size >= max_players) {
            return {
                "status": 403,
                "message": "Game is already full"
            }
        } else {
            let playersNodeRef = gamesRef.child(game_id).child("players");
            return playersNodeRef.transaction(t => {

                if (t === null) {
                    return new Map<String, Number>().set(uid, 1);//trying to set a map with the player data, when the /players is null
                } else {
                    let playersData: Map<String, Number> = t;
                    if (playersData.size >= max_players) { // rechecking
                        return;
                    } else {
                        playersData.set(uid, 1);
                        return playersData;
                    }
                }

            }).then(result => {
                if (result.committed) { // if true there is a commit and the transaction went through
                    return {
                        "status": 200,
                        "message": "User added to game successfully"
                    }
                } else {
                    return {
                        "status": 403,
                        "message": "Unable to add user at this time. Please try again"
                    }
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                return {
                    "status": 403,
                    "message": error
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
addUserToGame
Function execution took 1423 ms, finished with status code: 500
at /workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13401:38
at encode (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:179:18)
at Function.mapValues (/workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13400:7)
at baseForOwn (/workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2990:24)
at /workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4900:21
at keys (/workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13307:14)
at isArrayLike (/workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:11333:58)
at isFunction (/workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:11653:17)
at baseGetTag (/workspace/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:3067:51) 
at Object (<anonymous>)
Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

How can i set a map to `/players` node?

---

There were more than one issues with the code and as @Renaud pointed out, i have changed the 'once' callback to use promises version.
Also i had issues sending back data in the transaction. The data that i sent was using complex JS objects like Map(), but after some struggle (with the syntax) i changed it to a normal JS object (json like structure). Please see my changes below:

```
if (t === null) {
                    return [{ [uid]: { "status": 1 } }]; // if null, create an array and add an object to it
                } else {
                    let playersData = t;
                    if (playersData.size >= max_players) { // rechecking
                        return;
                    } else { // if not null create an object and add to the existing array
                        playersData.push({ 
                            [uid]: {
                                "status": 1
                            }
                        });
                        return playersData;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem most probably comes from the fact you are returning a complex JavaScript object, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52569728/3371862.

**In addition**, note that you should use the promise version of the [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once) method, since, in a Callable Cloud Function you must return a promise that resolves with the data object to send back to the client.

Instead of doing

```
return gameIDRef.once("value", function (snapshot) {...});
```

do

```
return gameIDRef.once("value").then(snapshot => {...});
```

With this you will be able to correctly build the [promise chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining) to be returned. Also, when dealing with the different cases around the `players` value, instead of returning JavaScript objects that will be handle in the `.then((result) => {...})` block (which is not necessary and not really logical), throw errors that will be handled in the `catch()` block.

Something along the following lines:

```
export const addUserToGame = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // Expected inputs - game_id(from data) and UID(from context)

  if (context.auth == null) {
    return {
      status: 403,
      message: 'You are not authorized to access this feature',
    };
    // IMHO better to do  throw new functions.https.HttpsError('...', ...);
  }

  const uid = context.auth.uid;
  const game_id = data.game_id;

  let gameIDRef = gamesRef.child(game_id);
  return gameIDRef
    .once('value')
    .then((snapshot) => {
      let players: Map<String, Number> = snapshot.child('players').val();
      let max_players: Number = snapshot.child('max_players').val();

      if (players != null && players.has(uid)) {
        throw new Error('Player already in the game');
      } else if (players != null && players.size >= max_players) {
        throw new Error('Game is already full');
      } else {
        let playersNodeRef = gamesRef.child(game_id).child('players');
        return playersNodeRef.transaction((t) => {
          if (t === null) {
            return new Map<String, Number>().set(uid, 1); //trying to set a map with the player data, when the /players is null
          } else {
            let playersData: Map<String, Number> = t;
            if (playersData.size >= max_players) {
              // rechecking
              return;
            } else {
              playersData.set(uid, 1);
              return playersData;
            }
          }
        });
      }
    })
    .then((result) => {
      if (result.committed) {
        // if true there is a commit and the transaction went through
        return {
          status: 200,
          message: 'User added to game successfully',
        };
      } else {
        // probably throw an error here
        return {
          status: 403,
          message: 'Unable to add user at this time. Please try again',
        };
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error.message === 'Player already in the game') {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('...', error.message);
      } else if (error.message === 'Game is already full') {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('...', error.message);
      } else {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', error.message);
      }
    });
});
```

See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors) for more details on how to handle errors in a Callable Cloud Function.

Comment: Many many thanks @Renaud Tamec. Its working finally. I have changed to promise version, changed error handling responses, and also changed the way i am setting the data in transaction. I will update my question with the changes that i made to the data